# How to get consolidated count of delimiter occurrence

Tags: python, linux, shell, awk

I have a requirement to fetch the count the occurrence of '|' in each line of a file then match the count with given inputcount, needs to throw exception when the count is wrong.

Say if the `inputcount=3` and the file has following content

```
s01|test|aaa|hh
S02|test|bbb
so3|test|ccc|oo
```

then exception should get thrown on executing the line 2 and it should exit the file.

Tried below Awk command to fetch the count for each lines, but I was not sure how to compare and throw the exception, when it not matches

```
awk ' {print (split($0,a,"\|")-1) }' test.dat
```

Can anyone please help me with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this awk:

```sh
awk -v inputcount=3 -F '\\|' 'NF && NF != inputcount+1 {exit 1}' file &&
 echo "good" || echo "bad"
```

**Details:**

- `-F '\\|'` sets `|` as input field separator
- `NF != inputcount+1` will return true if any line doesn't have `inputcount` pipe delimiters.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Since my file contains some of the line are empty, it always return bad. Can you please help me here

Comment: ok check updated answer. It will ignore empty lines now

Answer (score 2):

```
$ inputcount=3
$ awk -v c="$inputcount" 'gsub(/\|/,"&")  !=  c{exit 1}' file
$ echo $?
1
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try

```sh
awk -F '[|]' -v cols="$inputcount" 'NF != cols+1 {
    print FILENAME ":" FNR ":" $0 >"/dev/stderr"; exit 1 }' test.dat
```

The `-F` argument says to split on this delimiter; the number of resulting fields `NF` will be one more than there are delimiters, so we scream and die when that number is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As you also tagged the post with `python` I will write a python answer that could be a simple script.

The core is:

```py
with open(filename) as f:
    for n, line in enumerate(f):
        if line.count("|") != 3:
            print(f"Not valid file at line {n + 1}")
```

Than you can add some boilerplate:

```py
import fileinput
import sys

with fileinput.input() as f:
    for n, line in enumerate(f):
        if line.count("|") != 3:
            print(f"Not valid file at line {n + 1}")
            sys.exit(1)
```

And with `fileinput` you can accept almost any sort of input: see [Piping to a python script from cmd shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66225702/piping-to-a-python-script-from-cmd-shell/66225919#66225919)